# Why am I receving duplicate keys warning

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have a "Question" database table below:

```
SessionId (PK)    QuestionId (PK)  QuestionContent

MUL                    1           What is 2+2 and 3+3?
MUL                    2           Name three things you will find in a car?
MUL                    3           What are the four seasons?
```

Below are the errors I am receiving in mysqli:

> Duplicate entry 'RZC-1' for key 'PRIMARY' in /.../ on line 242
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1062): Duplicate entry 'RZC-2'
>   for key 'PRIMARY' in /.../on line 242
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1062): Duplicate entry 'RZC-3'
>   for key 'PRIMARY' in /.../on line 242

Why am I receiving errors on duplicate entries because I have stated that in question table, both "SessionId" and "QuestionId" are primary keys. Do I need to perform an SQL statement to mention that they are both composite keys?

Below is the mysqli code where it inserts the values into the "Question" table:

```
    var_dump($_POST);  

    $i = 0;
    $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

     $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');


        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }

    $insert->bind_param("sis", $sessid, $id, $_POST['questionText'][$i]);

            $insert->execute();

            if ($insert->errno) {
              // Handle query error here
            }

            $insert->close();
}
```

UPDATE:

DESCRIBE Question;

```
Field            Type          Null   Key  Default  Extra

SessionId        varchar(10)   NO     PRI  NULL
QuestionId       int(10)       NO     PRI  NULL
QuestionContent  varchar(5000) NO          NULL
```

Comment: have you declare both as composite primary key while creating table ??

Comment: I mentioned they are both primary keys but I don't know if there is suppose to be a sql command to declare composite keys or if you declare multiple primary keys then does it sort our composite key automatically?

Comment: Try ALTER TABLE Question DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (SessionId, QuestionId);

Comment: Nope, didn't work, still getting the mysqli errors on duplicate keys

Comment: I think I need to add a constraint, give me 2 mins to test it again

Comment: Nope still getting same error even if I did this in sql statement: ALTER TABLE Question DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD CONSTRAINT Question_Composite
 PRIMARY KEY (SessionId, QuestionId)

Comment: are your session ids really strings like "RZC" ? It seems quite likely the string you're passing as session id - is not the session id. As such you're passing the same string for all users and hence the sql errors. show `describe questions` - though it seems unlikely the table structure is the cause of your problems.

Comment: Yeah session id's are strings like "RZC", "AAA", "FRI" etc. At bottom of question I included output from DESCRIBE Question; statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){
    $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');

    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

    $insert->bind_param("sis", $sessid, $id, $_POST['questionText'][$i]);
    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) {
       // Handle query error here
    }

    $insert->close();
}
```

---

### 2 Issues:

1. You are looping and executing the same values more than once.  Either a new `$id` or `$sessid` needs to be set inside the loop - or perhaps you should do away with the loop entirely there.
2. You should set your SQL and Prepare statement outside the loop - they don't change and you're going against the purpose of a prepare statement.  My guess is you've misplaced your loop and only need to loop around the `bind_param()` and `execute()` statements

Comment: So can you show me what the updated php should look like? I will see if I can get it working but if you know what it should look like then please post it in your answer :)

Comment: if you don't understand the answer, you need to show more of your code

Comment: For performance, the prepare statement is supposed to act as a template.  You don't need to create that template more than once, which is why it should go outside the loop body.  The error, as [closh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/495288/closh) also said, is because you're looping and not setting a new value for the $id or $sessid.  It would work the first time, but at the second pass of the loop, those would have the same value as the first pass and so you get a duplicate key error.  --

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){
.....
$insert->bind_param("sis", $sessid, $id, $_POST['questionText'][$i]);
```

Looks that for the same  $sessid, $id you insert $c times row in loop.

Comment: Can you show me an update on what the php should look like. I know the sql and prepare statements shoud go out of the loop but what else should be in and out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

In the create table statement, you need to declare the composite primary key:

```
create table question (
sessionid char,
questionid int,
questioncontent varchar,
primary key(sessionid, questionid));
```

Comment: We tried it with ALTER TABLE (See comments) but still could not get it working.

Comment: @user1723760 Your table definition is correct according to your update `describe question;`. No need to change that. So, the only explanation I see is: you do have either duplicate session ids and/or duplicate question ids!

Comment: I do have duplicate session id's but because I am using 2 primary keys then it shouldn't be a problem, should it? Because Session Id 'MUL' QuestionId '1' and SesionId 'MUL' QuestionId '2', I mean yes SessionId are duplicate but this shouldn't be a problem is both SessionId and QuestionId are primary keys because it means together they are not duplicate.